# Certain dictionary key is overlooked/missed/not recognized during iteration in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I was trying to define a simple function to convert numbers expressed as string to real numbers. e.g 1234K to 1234000, 1234M to 1234000000. This can be easily done using if statement. Out of curiosity, I used dictionary instead and found out the following problem. Please see my code below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
dict_EN_num={"K":1000,'M':1000000}

def ENtoNum(value): 
    x=value    
    if type(x)==str:        
        for k,v in dict_EN_num.items():
            if k in x:
               x=int(x[:x.find(k)])*v
            break
    return x

y="1234K"
z="1234M"

print ENtoNum(y)
print ENtoNum(z)
```

The result in my iPython console was:

1234000

1234M

The conversion of variable y with "K" in it worked but the conversion of variable z with "M" failed.

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `break` needs to be indented one more level.